# Subquery returns more than 1 row - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE `pams_faker_lead_location` 
SET `location` = ( SELECT location FROM pams_leads WHERE pams_leads.location_id = pams_faker_lead_location.id   )
```

I dont know when i run the query in Mysql , this error occur.

> **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

anyone can help me solve the problem ?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You can also use Limit clause: UPDATE `pams_faker_lead_location` 
SET `location` = ( SELECT Distinct location FROM pams_leads WHERE pams_leads.location_id = pams_faker_lead_location.id  LIMIT 1 ) but its not a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT location FROM pams_leads WHERE pams_leads.location_id = pams_faker_lead_location.id
```

gives you more than 1 row.
You must change something because if you need update value you need **exactly one row**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question... This should go in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.`location` =  B.`location`
FROM `pams_faker_lead_location` A
JOIN `pams_leads` B ON B.location_id = A.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `joins` instead

```
update pams_faker_lead_location l
inner join pams_leads pm on pm.location_id = l.id
set l.location = pm.location
```

Comment: @WeiKang . . . This did not "solve" your problem.  It hid your problem.  You don't know which matching value is being used for the update.

Answer (score 0):

What part of the error message do you not get?  The subquery is returning more than one row, so you need to decide *which* value you want.  Here are two common methods for getting one row:

One uses an aggregation function, such as `MAX()` or `MIN()`:

```
UPDATE pams_faker_lead_location fll 
    SET location = (SELECT MAX(l.location)
                    FROM pams_leads l
                    WHERE l.location_id = fll.id
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

The other uses `LIMIT`.  This would normally have an `ORDER BY` as well, so you can choose the value you want:

```
UPDATE pams_faker_lead_location fll 
    SET location = (SELECT l.location
                    FROM pams_leads l
                    WHERE l.location_id = fll.id
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

The error is occurring because the data is not what you expect it to be.  Using a method such as `JOIN` merely hides the problem -- and might incur significant performance penalties if there are lots and lots of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ! @Gordan Linoff